# Java 8 Interface with default Methods not working when Jacoco Enabled

Tags: java, android, java-8, kotlin, jacoco

We are having an interface with **default methods** and we implemented that interface in both `Java` and `Kotlin` classes and we provided the implementation for the non default methods.

When we run in debug mode (which doesn't have testCoverageEnabled = true) and the app works as expected. But when we run in different config with testCoverageEnabled = true, the app is crashing with below error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method $$triggerInterfaceInit()V in class Lcom/ui/viewholders/CAViewContract$$CC; or its super classes (declaration of 'ui.viewholders.CAViewContract$$CC' appears in /data/app/SMCXbiLYvHb1Kk08Kee__g==/base.apk)
    at home.c.CCFragment.<clinit>(Unknown Source:0)
    at home.HomePageCardProvider.getFragment(HomePageCardProvider.java:17)
    at home.HomeFragment.handleCardFragment(HomeFragment.java:172)
```

**Note:**
1. JaCoCo version: "0.8.0"
2. Operating system: Android with minSdk 21

If we change the minSdk to 24, with `testCoverageEnabled = true` itself, it is working. We are not able to figure out the exact problem.

Comment: did you tried by adding Java 8 compatibility? https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support

Comment: Yes we have done that

Answer (score 2):

This problem can occur if you want to invoke the `default` implementation of a method that hasn't a `default` implementation in the `interface` that your class explicitly `implements` it. (But has a `default` implementation in a ***base (parent, super)* `interface`** of that `interface`).

Example: Suppose these defenitions:

```
class A implements DerivedInterface /*, ...*/ {
    @Override public void methodFromBaseInterface() {
        DerivedInterface.super.methodFromBaseInterface(); // Error:
            // NoSuchMethodError: No static method methodFromBaseInterface
    }
    // ...
}

interface DerivedInterface extends BaseInterface {
    // ... 
    // `methodFromBaseInterface` hasn't overriden here.
}

interface BaseInterface {
    default void methodFromBaseInterface() { /* ...*/ }
    // ...
}
```

Then execute:

```
A a = new A();
a.methodFromBaseInterface(); // This cause above error!
```

And you get an error at mentioned point!

<sup>*(Marginal note: You may need to define at least one method in `DerivedInterface` to avoid getting `NoClassDefFoundError` at runtime!)*</sup>

---

This is similar to a bug! *We used `super` keyword. Why expected **`static`** method?!!* Another point is that the above code hasn't any problem and you can run it in any Java 8 compatible environment without any problem!

*I think the problem is related to **incomplete support of Java 8 language APIs in Android platform**:*

> Android Studio 3.0 and later supports all Java 7 language features and **a subset of Java 8 language features that vary by platform version**.

Specially see ***Java 8 Language API** and **Compatible minSdkVersion*** table in [that page](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#supported_features):

> `java.lang.FunctionalInterface` : API level 24 or higher.

---

## Workarounds I found:

1. If you have access to the definition of `DerivedInterface` simply override `methodFromBaseInterface` and explicitly delegates it to its `super` interface:

   ```
   interface DerivedInterface extends BaseInterface {
       @Override default void methodFromBaseInterface() {
           BaseInterface.super.methodFromBaseInterface();
       }
       // ...
   }
   ```
2. Define a middle `class` that implements `BaseInterface` and derive `A` from it. Then run `methodFromBaseInterface` indirectly throw the middle `class`:

   ```
   class MiddleClass /*extends B*/ implements BaseInterface {}

   class A extends MiddleClass implements DerivedInterface {
       @Override public void methodFromBaseInterface() {
           super.methodFromBaseInterface(); // Indirectly from `MiddleClass`
       }
       // ...
   }
   ```

   Note: Uncomment `/*extends B*/` if your `A` class previously has a `super` named `B`.